# singleton, thread safe setters

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I have a singleton class that I ensure it is a singleton by doing

```
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
```

As documented before. Now I need to add an

```
NSMutableDictionary *selections
```

property to this singleton that other parts of the app will definitely update ( adding , reading key/value pairs).
So My question is how do I make sure this property is thread safe? 
declare it atomic? 
I need to make it's setters and getters thread safe !. 
I am a recent objective C programmer coming over from C#/ Java background, which is why I am a bit confused about this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a thread-safe and exception-safe way is use `@synchronized` to perform locking

```
@property (readonly) NSMutableDictionary *selections;

- (void)withSelection:(void (^)(NSMutableDictionary *))callback {
    if (!callback) return;
    @synchronized(self.selection) { // you need to make sure self.selection isn't nil
        callback(self.selection);
    }
}
```

---

```
__block NSDictionary *copiedSelection;

[[Singleton singleton] withSelection:^(NSMutableDictionary *selection) {
    // you can modify selection safely here
    copiedSelection= [selection copy];
}];

// you can use copiedSelection here
```

---

You can also use GCD with dispatch_queue to serialize operation on selection